# trying to write code for an addressbook in javascript but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write an addressbook in Javascript, HTML - but I can´t find the bug why it doesn´t work. I´m a really beginner so it would be very very kind if someone could help me that I understand the problem.

Here is the JS Code, where I created 3 objects and saved it in an array. I should try to create "Search", "Adding" and "Show all" but currently it doesn´t work anyway ...

```
var p1 = {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phone: "(0043) 650 111-1111",
    mail: "person1@google.com"
};

var p2 = {
    firstName: "Jane",
    lastName: "Doe",
    phone: "(0043) 650 222-2222",
    mail: "person2@google.com"
};

var p3 = {
    firstName: "August",
    lastName: "July",
    phone: "(0043) 650 333-3333",
    mail: "person3@google.com"
};
var contacts = [p1, p2, p3];

function addField() {
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("searching").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("listing").style.display ="none";
};

function searchField() {
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("searching").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("listing").style.display ="none";
};

function printPerson(person) {
    document.getElementById("person").innerHTML = ("Name: " + 
    contacts[i].firstName + "<br/>Nachname: " + contacts[i].lastName+ "
    <br/>Mail" + contacts[i].mail + "<br/>Phone:" + contacts[i].phone);
}

function listContacts() {
    document.getElementById('add').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("searching").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("listing").style.display = "block";
        var contactsLength = contacts.length;
        for (i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        printPerson(contacts[i]);
    }
};

function addContacts (firstName, lastName, phone, mail){
    this.firstName: document.getElementById("firstName").value,
    this.lastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value, 
    this.mail: document.getElementById("mail").value, 
    this.phone: document.getElementById("number").value,
};

function searchContacts(lastName) {
    var lastName = document.getElementById("last").value;
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        if (lastName === contacts[i].lastName) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        };
    };
};


function searchContacts(firstName) {
    var firstName = document.getElementById("first").value;
    var contactsLength = contacts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < contactsLength; i++) {
        if (firstName === contacts[i].lastName) {
            printPerson(contacts[i]);
        };
    };
};
```

my HTML: I´m not sure about using the innerHTML in JS correctly - it´s my fist time to write a complete HTML/JS

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Adressbook</title>
    <link href="s_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="s_jsfile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="main"> This is an addressbook </h1>
        <p id="test"> Please choose:</p><br/>
        <input class="buttons" type="button" value="Add new contact" 
        onClick="addField()"/>  
        <input class="buttons" type="button" value="Search contact" 
        onClick="searchField()" />
        <input class="buttons" type="button" value="Show all contacts" 
      onClick="listContacts()" />
    <div hidden id="add">
        <p>
        First Name: <input class="add" type="text" id="firstName" value=""/>
        <br/>
        Last Name: <input class="add" type="text" id="lastName" value=""/><br/>
        Phone: <input type="text" id="phone" value=""/><br/>
        Mail: <input type="text" id="mail" value=""/><br/>
        <button type="button" onclick="addContacts()">Add Contact</button> </p>
    </div>

    <div hidden id="searching">
        <input type="text" id="searchword" placeholder="Enter a name" />
        <button type="button" onclick="searchContacts();">Search</button></p>
    </div>

    <div hidden id="listing">
        <p> Full Adressbook: <br/>
        <span id="person" ></span> <br/>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please define "*doesn't work*"? What is the intended functionality, and how does the current functionality differ?

Comment: The problem is among the missing search-result displayed on the site that it doesn´t show every person in the list - just the first one and I tried to find a solution but the loop isn´t a loop in that case

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your print method you're referencing what to print with expressions like `contacts[i].firstName` when `i` isn't defined in that function and you've already passed in the person object itself!

Here's an example of a corrected version

```
function printPerson(person) {
    document.getElementById("person").innerHTML = ("Name: " + person.firstName);
}
```

Notice: `person.firstName` instead of `contacts[i].firstName`

---

Also be sure to notice your search is case sensitive!